# What the relationship between these two functions?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am given that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are continuous real-valued functions on $[0,5]$ with
$$
\int_0^a f(x) \, dx + \int_a^5 g(x) \, dx = 5
$$
where $a\in [0,5]$.

So to summarize $$ F(a)-F(0)+G(5)-G(a) = 5$$

What’s the relationship between $f$ and $g$?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange. While asking questions, please include what you have tried or thought about the problem (like what leads you have, how you are thinking about it) so that, instead of having to write a full solution explaining it all, users can start from where you left off. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Is that sum equal to $5$ for EVERY value of $a,$ or for one special value of $a,$ or what?

Comment: As I understand it’s supposed to be for every value, but I’m not sure, and I can’t check it since a friend asked me this.

Comment: @BatiDyDx: If it holds for every $0<a<5$, then you may try to use the fundamental theorem of calculus and differentiate with respect to $a$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Differentiate (with respect to $a$) and apply the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Comment: And what if l had a constant value for $a$. Say maybe $a=2$

Comment: @BatiDyDx Then you probably can't say much, to be honest.